# Array of different elements in ListView

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I have these arrays:

ImageView aImages[], TextView aTextViewName[], Button aBuy[]

All arrays have same count of elements.

I want to create something like ListView that will take aImages[n], aTextViewName[n] and aBuy[n] from array and put it in a list like one element. Also it must create button listener for each button from list element.

I mean that first element in the list gets programly, and after I click on button - the are second element added to list. When I clicked on button of second element - the are third element added to list. And so on.

So there are three questions:
1) How make image, text, and button like single element but with access to each element (if I want to change text, but leave image, and button)? 
2) How make dynamical adding these elements to list?
3) What can I use to store this elements?

)

Comment: Questions 1 and 2 solved. Thanks to user2905379

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you can use arraylist of object. for example:

```
public class Test{
   ImageView aImages;
   TextView aTextViewName;
   Button aBuy
}
```

then in your activity you can create and arraylist of test object.

```
ArrayList testList = new ArrayList<Test>();
```

2) when user click on add button store those detail to the testList and call notifyDataSetChanged() to update the listview.

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

3) you may try to use sqlite if you are looking to store the data permanently

Comment: Thank you!
Did you have any ideas about question (3) ? :)

Comment: below is some documentation and great tutorial you can refer to
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html
please accept my answer